# How to use dispatch_queue_create in Swift 2.0?

Tags: swift2

In swift 1.2, create a dispatch queue just like this:

```
dispatch_queue_create("imageProcessingQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
```

But in swift 2.0, it has an error:

```
 Cannot invoke 'dispatch_queue_create' with an argument list of type '(String, dispatch_queue_attr_t!)'
```

`dispatch_queue_create` want an `UnsafePointer<Int8>` type, how can I get that.

Answer (score 11):

I had this issue too, when assigning to a `lazy var`. I was able to bypass the error by explicitly adding a type to my variable:

```
lazy var myQueue: dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_queue_create("imageProcessingQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
```

Comment: Thank you nate! Only had this with Swift 2.3 :/

Answer (score 1):

The error message is confusing. Most likely it originates from some code surrounding (most likely immediately preceding) this code.

To verify, create a new Playground and run this - it compiles without errors:

```
import Foundation
let queue = dispatch_queue_create("label", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
```